# Improve A Tikz Flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts, workflow

[image: Flowchart]

How can I add the circles as shown in the above flowchart so I can number each process? Now my optimum goal is to show a process using a flowchart and describe each box under the flowchart so I came up with the idea of putting a number on each box then describe it below.

If possible help me putting these circles or if possible propose another way.

The code:

```
                \documentclass{standalone}
            \usepackage{tikz}
            
            \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
            \tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
            \tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
            \tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
            \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
            \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
            
            
            \begin{document}
            
                \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
                \small
                \node (start) [startstop] {Start};
                \node (dec1) [decision, right of=start, xshift=1.5cm,align=center] {Decision1};
                \draw [arrow] (start) -- (dec1);
                \node (pro1) [process, right of=dec1, xshift=1.75cm,align=center] {Process};
                \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=south] {No} (pro1);
                \node (dec2) [decision, below of=dec1, yshift=-0.95cm,align=center] {Decision2};
                \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=west] {Yes} (dec2);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            
            \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `append after command` to define a style that adds these circles. For instance,

```
clabel=1 between north west and north east
```

places the node at the upper edge, and

```
clabel=2 between north and east
```

puts it on the upper right diagonal. Please note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, and so is your method of positioning nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30},
io/.style={trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30},
process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30},
decision/.style={diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30},
arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth},
clabel/.style args={#1 between #2 and #3}{append after command={
(\tikzlastnode.#2) -- (\tikzlastnode.#3) 
node[pos=0.5,circle,draw,font=\sffamily,fill=white,inner sep=1pt]{#1}
}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3em and 2.5em,nodes={font=\small\sffamily,align=center}]
    \node (start) [startstop,clabel=1 between north west and north east] {Start};
    \node (dec1) [decision, right=of start,clabel=2 between north and east] {Decision1};
    \draw [arrow] (start) -- (dec1);
    \node (pro1) [process, right=of dec1,clabel=3 between north west and north east] {Process};
    \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=south] {No} (pro1);
    \node (dec2) [decision, below=of dec1,clabel=4 between north and east] {Decision2};
    \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=west] {Yes} (dec2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean just adding cricles like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
            \usepackage{tikz}
            
            \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
            \tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
            \tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
            \tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
            \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
            \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
            
            
            \begin{document}
            
                \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
                \small
                \node (start) [startstop] {Start};
                \node (dec1) [decision, right of=start, xshift=1.5cm,align=center] {Decision1};
                \draw [arrow] (start) -- (dec1);
                \node (pro1) [process, right of=dec1, xshift=1.75cm,align=center] {Process};
                \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=south] {No} (pro1);
                \node (dec2) [decision, below of=dec1, yshift=-0.95cm,align=center] {Decision2};
                \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=west] {Yes} (dec2);
                
                %adds circles
                \draw [thick] (0,0.5) circle (4pt);
                \draw [thick] (4.3,0.5) circle (4pt);
                \draw [thick] (7,0.5) circle (4pt);
                \draw [thick] (2.7,-2.5) circle (4pt);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            
            \end{document}
```

[image]

With numbers inside:

```
               \draw [thick] (0,0.5) circle (4pt);
                \node at (0,0.5) {1};
                \draw [thick] (4.3,0.5) circle (4pt);
                \node at (4.3,0.5) {2};
                \draw [thick] (7,0.5) circle (4pt);
                \node at (7,0.5) {3};
                \draw [thick] (2.7,-2.5) circle (4pt);
                \node at (2.7,-2.5) {4};
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. I want it to be more systematic. I mean the circle is done automatically and centered nicely. Also, the background of the circle should show what is under it.